# Ошибка при запуске пула IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Запускаю пул для mvc приложения на IIS. Всё работало. Но я добавил в приложение EntityFramework и mssql сервер. Появилась ошибка. Я установил mssqllocaldb 12 версии mssql сервера. И создал экземпляр с таким же названием как и в приложении. Но всё равно осталась ошибка. Вот текст ошибки:

> При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Произошла ошибка Local Database Runtime.Не удалось получить путь к данным локального приложения. Вероятнее всего, не загружен профиль пользователя. Если экземпляр LocalDB выполняется под управлением IIS, проверьте, включена ли загрузка профиля для текущего пользователя.
>   )

Возможно у меня не включена загрузка профиля для текущего пользователя. Но я даже не знаю что это такое. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить эту ситуацию.

Comment: Начнём с простых вопросов на сто рублей. Вы не пишете ничего про то, что вы добавили коннекшн стринг. Добавляли? Если да - приведите её в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @AK конечно конекшен стринг есть. У меня же работает эта программа если запускать её не из пула а просто из visual studio. `<add name="Connect" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\StatisticsDiagram\StatisticsDiagram\App_Data\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Так ведь LocalDB не предназначен для работы в службах же...

Comment: _"Возможно у меня не включена загрузка профиля для текущего пользователя."_ хмм.. ну попробуйте включить. Пул работает от какого то пользователя и в свойствах пула есть опция, которая включает загрузку профиля этого самого пользователя.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не знаю. Поэтому и задал вопрос. Подскажите пожалуйста как должно тогда работать?

Comment: @i-one а можно поподробнее где такое можно включить? Желательно если есть какая нибудь статейка или может вы сможете объяснить куда нужно конкретно заходить?

Comment: Скорее всего зависит от версии IIS и Windows, но примерно: Start(Пуск) > IIS Manager (выбрать или найти) > Application Pools > выбрать нужный пул приложений (или создать отдельный) > Advanced Settings > Load User Profile. Статейка, хмм... [вот](https://windowsnotes.ru/iis/application-pool-identities-v-iis/) какая-то (по крайне мере про пулы и про профиль там есть).

Comment: @i-one 10 windows. У меня всё на русском. И ничего похожего в настройках пула не нашёл.

Comment: @i-one загрузить профиль пользователя. Нашёл. Он и таак стоит в значении true.

Comment: @AK ну что? Что то можете подсказать?

Comment: А какое identity у пула, в котором работает приложение? И есть ли у него права на директорию, в которой располагаются файлы БД? Попробуйте дать права, если их нет (в статье по ссылке - "Настройка доступа к ресурсам").

Comment: @i-one права есть. Приложение же раньше работало добавился только сам файл mdf. То есть дериктория доступна. Identity погляжу, напишу, вы не подскажете где оно там конкретно написано?

Comment: @i-one нашёл. ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: Раньше, например, могло работать с правами на чтение (смотря что делает приложение, впрочем), а с добавлением БД требуются права и на запись тоже. Проверьте что у пользователя `IIS AppPool\имя пула приложений` есть права на чтение и изменения в каталоге с БД.

Comment: Если права есть и ошибка остаётся, то посмотрите по ссылкам ([раз](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/), [два](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/), [три](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31089097/2523686)), вдруг что-то подойдёт.

Comment: @i-one а как поглядеть есть ли права у этого пула в нужные каталоги?

Comment: @i-one но о5 же мне что то подсказывает что ошибка не в этом, потому что в тексте написано что вообще сервер не найден.

Comment: @i-one но я проверю только напишите пожалуйста как поглядеть есть ли у конкретного пула доступ к определённым каталогам.